# Why can't I get rid of the space below this image?

Tags: html, css, image

I've been working on this for the past few hours and I give up.  I cannot figure this one out.

I have an image (header logo), followed by a nav bar.  There is a 2-3px space just below the image.  I've systematically eliminated every bit of externally referenced CSS, and then added some inline CSS to try and fix the problem.  Here's what I have right now:

```
<html lang='en'>
        <head>
            <meta charset='utf-8' />
            <title>Sci-fi's Big Mistake</title>
        </head>

        <body style='margin:0px; padding:0px; border:1px solid green;'>


            <img src='/images/farscape.jpg'  alt='Farscape style='margin:0px; padding:0px; border:1px solid red;'><br>
            <span style='border:1px solid blue;margin:0px; padding:0px; '>text</span>
            <ul id='menu' class='gold' style='margin:0px; padding:0px; border:1px solid red;'>
                <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
                <li class='active'><a href='#'>About</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Services</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Products</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
                </ul>




Shouldn't have cancelled this.
</body></html>
```

Here's a screenshot of the page, and what I'm seeing on my system (Win, xp, same in IE8 as well as FF 13)

http://picturepush.com/public/8737985

Comment: Is there any external style sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you got it.

http://jsfiddle.net/dennym/XBdfk/

Removed the `<br>` and added a `display:block` to your image.
The space is gone.

The Problem was the `<br>` it has a min margin which u cant remove... i guess.
Also you have to add a `display:block` to your image, so the text appears at the bottom.

(Also removed a little error in your quotation marks)

Answer (score 1):

The image tag code is not correct you didn't close the alt attribute so the styles aren't taking affect and you should be using double quotes

```
<img src='/images/farscape.jpg'  alt='Farscape style='margin:0px; padding:0px; border:1px solid red;'><br>
```

You also may want to remove the `<br>` and set `display:block;` on the image

Comment: That may be a type-o in copying over.  It's a development (aka private to the world) site, but I will post up the code (same as above, but i'll remove the actual client content & text first, like above).

Comment: Confirmed that the missing quote is actually there on the live site.   I've never seen where using double quotes causes random spacing.   I use singles so I can double quote the variable in PHP that holds all of this HTML, then echo to the screen.  I prefer embedding variables in the double quotes as opposed to having to 'break' . $up . 'content' with single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no gap for me using Mac OS X/Chrome. My guess would be that your browser is setting a line-height on the span other than 1.

Try using a reset stylesheet, http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/. Also [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) will easily allow you to hover over elements to see what sizes elements to pin-point where the padding is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

If understand you correctly, the problem is caused by the fact that images are not only inline elements like text, but are also considered to be 'text'. Text is written with a baseline. Most letters align on this baseline, but some, like j, g and y not. So some pixels of space are included at the bottom, below the baseline when a text is rendered.
You can put this off by adding

```
line-height:0px;
```

to your image tag.

Another bizarre result of this image-equals-letter idea is that images that should be aligned side by side show a gap. Indeed: there are spaces between letters! You can solve this by adding to that sme image tag:

```
font-size:0px;
```

---

Another way to solve that problem you mention would be to make that header image the background image of a div with the same dimensions. Div's are only containers and have no font-like properties.

Hope this helps!